# Fill one row in 2D array outside the process (VHDL)

Tags: arrays, matrix, vhdl

I have array:

```
type MATR is array(natural range 1 to N, natural range 1 to N) of natural;
signal m: MATR;
```

1) Is it possible to fill elements m(0, 1), m(0, 2) ... m(0, N) with some value outside of process?  Something like:

```
m(1) <= (others => 2)
```

2) Is it possible assign 1D array(range 1 to N) to one row of 2D array (Also outside of process)?

Comment: I have seen you accepted my answer as a solution. Which tool chains do you use? I'm interested in synthesis proofs for the Vivado or Quartus II tool chain.

Comment: I use Xilinx 14.4, your code works. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can do this by writing a procedure like this one:

```
procedure assign_row(signal slm : out T_SLM; slv : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR; constant RowIndex : NATURAL) is
  variable temp : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(slm'high(2) downto slm'low(2));  -- Xilinx iSIM work-around, because 'range(2) evaluates to 'range(1); tested with ISE XST/iSim 14.2
begin
  temp := slv;
  for i in temp'range loop
    slm(RowIndex, i)  <= temp(i);
  end loop;
end procedure;
```

Where T_SLM is my matrix type defined like this:

```
-- STD_LOGIC_MATRIXs
type T_SLM is array(NATURAL range <>, NATURAL range <>) of STD_LOGIC;
-- ATTENTION:
-- 1. you MUST initialize your matrix signal with 'Z' to get correct simulation results (iSim, vSim, ghdl/gtkwave)
--    Example: signal myMatrix : T_SLM(3 downto 0, 7 downto 0) := (others => (others => 'Z'));
-- 2. Xilinx iSIM work-around: DON'T use myMatrix'range(n) for n >= 2
--    because: myMatrix'range(2) returns always myMatrix'range(1); tested with ISE/iSim 14.2
-- USAGE NOTES:
--  dimension 1 => rows     - e.g. Words
--  dimension 2 => columns  - e.g. Bits/Bytes in a word
```

So here is an example to use this procedure:

```
architecture [...]
  signal myVector : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(7 downto 0);
  signal myMatrix : T_SLM(3 downto 0, myVector'range) := (others => (others => 'Z'));
  [...]
begin
  [...]
  assign_row(myMatrix, myVector, 0);
  assign_row(myMatrix, (myVector'range => '0'), 1);
  assign_row(myMatrix, x"4A", 2);
  [...]
end;
```

This code is tested with ISE XST and iSim (13.x, 14.x), vSim and GHDL. As ISE 13.x was the current release, Xilinx stated that the range-bug will not be fixed in ISE 14.x.

If you need the other way around, here is my function get_row:

```
-- get a matrix row
function get_row(slm : T_SLM; RowIndex : NATURAL) return STD_LOGIC_VECTOR is
  variable slv : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(slm'high(2) downto slm'low(2));       -- Xilinx iSim work-around, because 'range(2) = 'range(1); tested with ISE/iSim 14.2
begin
  for i in slv'range loop
    slv(i)  := slm(RowIndex, i);
  end loop;
  return slv;
end function;
```

If you want to use NATURAL as the elementary type for the vectors and matrices, then exchange STD_LOGIC with NATURAL.

Answer (score 0):

**1) Is it possible to fill elements m(0, 1), m(0, 2) ... m(0, N) with some value outside of process?**

**2) Is it possible assign 1D array(range 1 to N) to one row of 2D array (Also outside of process)?**

Yes it's possible.  I'll only give an example for loading a new row.  Note this example is for N = 4, the method can be impractical for larger arrays.

Also note this only allows stactic indices.

```
entity foo is
    constant N: natural := 4;
end entity;

architecture fum of foo is
    type MATR is array(natural range 1 to N, natural range 1 to N) of natural;
    type col is array (natural range 1 to N) of natural;
    constant f:col := (1,2,3,4);
    signal m: MATR;

begin
    m <=  (1 => ( 1 => f(1),    2 => f(2),    3 => f(3),   4 => f(4)), 
           2 => ( 1 => m(2,1),  2 => m(2,2),  3 => m(2,3), 4 => m(2,4)),
           3 => ( 1 => m(3,1),  2 => m(3,2),  3 => m(3,3), 4 => m(3,4)),
           4 => ( 1 => m(4,1),  2 => m(4,2),  3 => m(4,3), 4 => m(4,4)));

end architecture;
```

(And perhaps your question(s) should be a bit more explicit.  For your purposes the answer may not be practicable.)