# How do I setup entity for a 1 to 2^n output demux with n select lines using VHDL?

Tags: vhdl

I am working on a assignment do make a demux with 2^n outputs with n select lines. I have a my input (x bit wide, in this case x is 32bits) and my enable pins taken care of. But I don't know how to go about setting up entity so that my output is 2^n with n select lines. So far my entity declaration looks like:

```
-- Entity declaration
entity DEMUX is
-- Get the size of an integer
generic(Len :integer);
-- Map input, output, selection and enable signal ports
port(
   Inp : in std_logic_vector(Len-1 downto 0); -- Input pin
   Ena : in std_logic; -- Enable pin
   Sel : --How to set select lines?
   Oup : --How to set outputs?
);
end DEMUX;
```

So basically I have a demux that is taking one input that is x bits in width ("01001011" sequence of 32 bits). I want to take that and pass it along on the other side of the demux where it take 2^n number of paths. The select line determines which path to take. I wanted to know how to setup entity declaration for the output and the select pin.

Comment: Your question is not clear: what do you want the select pins to do and what do you want the output to show?

Comment: @J.H.Bonarius I have updated the question above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you properly, you have one input (x-bits) and 2^n outputs (each x-bits)
Easiest is to define an unconstrained array data type in a separate package. (note: this is VHDL-2008!)

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;

package array_type is
    type std_logic_vector_array is array (natural range <>) of std_logic_vector; 
end package;

library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use work.array_type.all;

-- Entity declaration
entity DEMUX is
    -- Get the size of an integer
    generic(
        x : positive;
        n : positive
    );
    -- Map input, output, selection and enable signal ports
    port(
       Inp : in  std_logic_vector(x-1 downto 0);
       Ena : in  std_logic;
       Sel : in  std_logic_vector(0 to n-1);
       Oup : out std_logic_vector_array(0 to (2**n)-1)(x-1 downto 0)
    );
end DEMUX;
```

edit: I just found [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28468334/using-array-of-std-logic-vector-as-a-port-type-with-both-ranges-using-a-generic) explaining the same.