# Using generic for a type in a port entity in VHDL 93

Tags: vhdl

I have a type declared in a package which I use in the port entity:

Package:

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;

package ports_type is
    constant N: positive := 3;
    type t_ports_types is array(0 to N-1) of std_logic_vector (N-1 downto 0);    
end package ports_type;
```

Module:

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
use work.ports_type.all;

entity ports is
    generic (
        N : positive := 3
    );
    port(
        inp     : in t_ports_types;
        outp    : out std_logic_vector(N-1 downto 0)
    );
end ports;

architecture Behavioral of ports is

begin

    process(inp)
        variable result : std_logic;
    begin
        for y in 0 to N-1 loop
            result := '0';
            for x in 0 to N-1 loop
                result := result or inp(x)(y);
            end loop;
            outp(y) <= result;
        end loop;
    end process; 

end Behavioral;
```

The problem is that I have to manually change the value of `N`in the package, which is a problem if I want to instantiate the ports entity in another module, like:

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
use work.ports_type.all;

entity ports_top is
    generic (
        N : positive := 3
    );
    Port ( 
        A       : in std_logic_vector(N-1 downto 0);
        B       : in std_logic_vector(N-1 downto 0);
        C       : in std_logic_vector(N-1 downto 0);
        Outp    : out std_logic_vector(N-1 downto 0)
    );
end ports_top;

architecture Behavioral of ports_top is

    signal s_ports : t_ports_types;

begin

    s_ports(0) <= A;
    s_ports(1) <= B;
    s_ports(2) <= C;

    ports_0: entity work.ports(Behavioral)
        generic map (
            N => N
        )
        port map(
            inp => s_ports,
            outp => Outp
        );

end Behavioral;
```

The goal would be to only change N in the top module and not in the package as well. Is that possible with vhdl'93?
Thanks for the help.

Comment: VHDL has blocks, not modules. `Is that possible with vhdl'93? ` No. You use N in both the dimension of array type `t_ports_types` as well as it's element subtype which means it can't be an unconstrained array type. -2008 introduces unbounded array types which allow both the dimension and the element dimension to be supplied by an object declaration of an unbounded array type. in -1993 an array type is not allowed to have an unconstrained element subtype. The element simple name doesn't denote it's subtype without a constraint.

Comment: So is there another alternative then?

Comment: No. (Other than using -2008. If there had been there'd have been no reason to add unbounded array types.)

Comment: See the tricks listed at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28468334/using-array-of-std-logic-vector-as-a-port-type-with-both-ranges-using-a-generic, basically using a 1D view of the array

Comment: I thought about that but then I would have one BIG input and I need them to be A, B, C,...,M rather than input : std_logic_vector(M*N-1 downto 0)